# symfony2 fatal error Cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, symfony, fatal-error

Ok, I've been at this for two hours now and I see some other people have had this error, but I can't seem to match their causes/resolutions with mine.

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Cannot redeclare class companycontroller in /var/www/biztv_symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php on line 55

The terminal gives a better error message pointing me to the end clause of the actual class that it reports having trouble with (trying to redeclare).

If I remove or rename the file companyController.php it throws a Symfony2 error saying that the it went looking for the class but didn't find it where it was expected.

If I put the file back in its place, apache throws a php error saying that the class companyController can't be redeclared.

I only have it once?!

Here is the entire class... if anyone has patience to try and help me out...

```
<?php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company;
use BizTV\BackendBundle\Form\companyType;

/**
 * company controller
 *
 */

class companyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all company entities.
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('BizTVBackendBundle:company')->findAll();

        return $this->render('BizTVBackendBundle:company:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a company entity.
     *
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BizTVBackendBundle:company')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find company entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('BizTVBackendBundle:company:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),

        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new company entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new company();
        $form   = $this->createForm(new companyType(), $entity);

        return $this->render('BizTVBackendBundle:company:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new company entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        $entity  = new company();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form    = $this->createForm(new companyType(), $entity);
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            /* Create adminuser for this company to go along with it */
            $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
            $user = $userManager->createUser();

            //make password (same as username)
            $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user); //get encoder for hashing pwd later
            $tempPassword = $entity->getCompanyName(); //set password to equal company name

            //Get company
            $tempCompanyId = $entity->getId(); //get the id of the just-inserted company (so that we can retrieve that company object below for relating it to the user object later)
            $tempCompany = $em->getRepository('BizTVBackendBundle:company')->find($tempCompanyId); //get the company object that this admin-user will belong to

            $user->setUsername($entity->getCompanyName() . "/admin"); //set username to $company/admin
            $user->setEmail('admin.'.$entity->getCompanyName().'@example.com'); //set email to non-functioning (@example)
            $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($tempPassword, $user->getSalt())); //set password with hash
            $user->setCompany($tempCompany); //set company for this user            
            $user->setConfirmationToken(null); //we don't need email confirmation of account
            $user->setEnabled(true); //without a confirmation token, we of course also need to flag the account as enabled manually
            $user->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('company_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

        }

        return $this->render('BizTVBackendBundle:company:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing company entity.
     *
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BizTVBackendBundle:company')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find company entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createForm(new companyType(), $entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('BizTVBackendBundle:company:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Edits an existing company entity.
     *
     */
    public function updateAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BizTVBackendBundle:company')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find company entity.');
        }

        $editForm   = $this->createForm(new companyType(), $entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $editForm->bindRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('company_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return $this->render('BizTVBackendBundle:company:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a company entity.
     *
     */
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('BizTVBackendBundle:company')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find company entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('company'));
    }

    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id))
            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to grep for `companyController`?

Comment: you do no have namespace defined in your controller. Maybe could be that?

Comment: Thank you. I just regenerated the crud for the entity and that is what I found out too - late last night I added a comment to the top of the document - must have accidentally highlighted the namespace line just as I started typing my comment, thus replacing the namespace with a comment...

Is it not possible to mark this comment of yours as the answer to the thread?

Comment: Ensure that you don't have two methods with the same name in the class. I spotted I had two `indexAction` methods in my class and this was the error I was seeing.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So, turns out that was a clumpsy typo by moi there.

But for anyone else who runs into this error message in Symfony2:

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Cannot redeclare class...

Here is a hint: check if you have accidentally deleted or typo:ed the namespace in the file that contains the definition of the class that php claims it is trying to re-define.

The php error message doesn't really give you a clue to look for that... =)

Comment: Mark this answer as accepted, so this question will not be filtered by `Unanswered`

Comment: I had similar errors with fresh Symfony installation (just downloaded, unpacked, without any modifications) - it turned out that problems were generated by APC (files included using 'require' are cached by APC). So my advice is to try switch off APC if you don't find any errors in your files. :)

Comment: I found this q/a when Symfony2 PropelBundle started to report 'Fatal Error: Cannot redefine AdHocTask', preventing model and sql builds.

For anyone else arriving here with the same Propel error, clearing Symfony's cache worked a treat.

Comment: Hell yeah, typo too. Seeing the number of upvotes, I'm guessing we symfo programmers are clumsy :)

Comment: @Marek, in layman's terms... nuke the caches. I did so in var/cache app/cache `bin\console cache:clear` and then rebuild with `composer install`. I got an error about ContainerAwareInterace when ugrading from 2.4 to 3.1.

Comment: Hello, I have this error on an Entity in Symfony 3.4 and I don't understand why because the name of the class is unique for the entire project (including vendors) and it works since few months before now. I made some changes which aren't related to that class so I'm searching where the problem comes from... What does that mean `typo:ed the namespace` ?

Comment: Update : I found the source of my error. I had 2 classes with the same name but the file of the 2nd was only on the server side and not in my local files structure. They should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I juste removed cache manually and it worked

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

Clearing cache was not fixing my problem.

Comment: Somethimes removing only cache might not enough. 
Run "composer dump-autoload" if required.

Answer (score 0):

redeclare class - Likely there is tow classes with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you got seduced by copy/paste, check your classnames, namespaces and for other "typos" that could have happened. (copy/paste is the devil of programming :/)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, in my case I had renamed the class but not the containing file. Every class should be declared in a file with the same name. So check that, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a `use` statement under the namespace which used the same classname (but another path).

```
namespace Bsz\RecordTab;
use \Bsz\Config\Libraries; // I used  this in constructor
class Libraries 
{
...
}
```

Without the use directive, it Worked