# Cannot redeclare class, controller Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

My project was worked fine but when I added a new **"Category"** entity , this error appears but I do not have another Class with same name

**Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Project\SotreBundle\Controller\CategoryDashboardController**

and this is the controller: **CategoryDashboardController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Project\SotreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;

use Project\SotreBundle\Entity\Category;


use Project\SotreBundle\Form\Type\CategoryType;
use Project\SotreBundle\Form\Type\CategoryEditType;



/**
* Category controller.
*
*/
class CategoryDashboardController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Lists all Categories
 *
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $listCategories = $em->getRepository('ProjectStoreBundle:Category')->findAll();

    return $this->render('ProjectDashboardBundle:Category:index.html.twig',
    array(
        'listCategories' => $listCategories
    ));
}

}
```

Comment: There's always more to that error message. It should tell you **exactly** where the class was first defined and **exactly** where you're attempting to redefine it. Where's the rest?

Comment: Also, are you using APC? If so, see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776145/symfony2-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class#comment18784380_11776520)

Comment: This happened to me once and I solved it clearing the cache. Try `app/console cache:clear --no-warmup` . Of course, use `--env=prod` if in a production environment