# What is causing the error "Cannot declare class className because the name is already in use"

Tags: yii2

I cannot find the cause of this error.

I have a model (school profile) that has a relation to another model (fields of study).

When I try to access the related model I get the error "Cannot declare class app\models\FieldOfStudy because the name is already in use"

I am not aware of using it anywhere else.

Relation code:

```
public function getFieldsOfStudy()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FieldOfStudy::className(), ['fieldOfStudyId' => 'fieldOfStudyId'])
        ->viaTable('schoolProfileFieldOfStudyXref', ['schoolProfileId' => 'schoolProfileId']);
}
```

I am trying to access the related model like so:

```
$schoolProfile->fieldsOfStudy;
```

The thing that is particularly frustrating is that I use these same classes in another project. I have never seen this error. The error output indicates that the error is happening in the above hasMany function when it simply tries to load the class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, i see you resolved it... I was thinking of more subtle reasons not that you had a typo... that is the first thing you need to check. Go ahead and accept your own answer, who knows when somebody else comes with a typo and instead of checking the obvious goes ahead and asks it on SO first... This kind of stuff is priceless anyway.

Comment: I have hundreds of class files, I don't know why this ONE had a typo, the namespaces were generated, this is one of those times where perhaps a completely unintended keystroke did the damage. The point here (to me) is that I would have never associated this error (because of the seemingly misleading error message) with a misspelled namespace.

Answer (score 2):

I had a typo in the namespace declaration in the FieldOfStudy class. I got the idea to check it from this post: [symfony2 fatal error Cannot redeclare class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776145/symfony2-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class)

The exact part of the post that helped out was:

"Here is a hint: check if you have accidentally deleted or typo:ed the namespace in the file that contains the definition of the class that php claims it is trying to re-define."